# Determine the center of the cluster with the most points

Tags: python, cluster-analysis

After performing clustering on a dataset with GPS locations using KMeans, is there a way to determine the cluster with the most points, i.e. the largest cluster and then associate one of the centers with this specific cluster?

Suppose my code is:

```
kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=4)
kmeans.fit(points)
```

I know I can print the centers via:

```
print(kmeans.cluster_centers_) -> e.g [[lat1, long1], [lat2, long2], ...]
```

and the determine the amount of points of each cluster via:

```
print(Counter(kmeans.labels_)) -> e.g. Counter({0: 510, 1: 200, 2: 50, 3: 44})
```

How can I now link the largest cluster (the one with 510 points) to the correct center coordinates? Is this possible in Python?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the largest cluser label using argmax on the counter values and link to centers just indexing.

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
from collections import Counter

points = np.random.normal(0, 3, size=(100, 2))

kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=4)
kmeans.fit(points)

counter = Counter(kmeans.labels_)
largest_cluster_idx = np.argmax(counter.values())
largest_cluster_center = kmeans.cluster_centers_[largest_cluster_idx ]
```

Comment: Thanks. But doesn't this rely on that the order of kmeans.labels_ corresponds to the order of kmeans.cluster_centers_? And I am not sure if they correspond. For example if we have: Counter({3: 30, 1: 28, 0: 23, 2: 19}) this would mean that the third cluster has the most points, but your code would say the index is 0 and return the first coordinate from the center-array.

Comment: I'm just in general unsure about the order of cluster_centers_. In what way does the order of the elemens of the array correspond to the clusters? Is the first element the center of the cluster 0 or the center of the largest cluster? I can find no documentation about it.

Answer (score 0):

The index 0 in labels corresponds to center 0, the index 1 to center 1.

Everything else would be madness, wouldn't it?

Even if you would automatically order them by size (which would break some things), you'd then also update labels, because users need to be able to find the right center for each point.

Also the theory that they are reordered by size is easy to refute: just run it a few more times on different days, and you'll find counterexamples. In particular, if you use `reversed(cluster_centers_)` as initialization, then it should finish within one iteration and give them in this reversed order.